# Website not validating on W3C, BootStrap framework

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to validate my website via W3C, however once uploaded I get the following error:

```
Fatal Error: Empty document, with no root element.
```

and

```
Info: The Content-Type was application/octet-stream. Using the XML parser (not resolving external entities).
```

What is the issue?

Any help would be much appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>My Websitee</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The first error, I don't get that pasting it into the validator. The second error is a misconfiguration of your server. It's not serving the pages as text/html

Comment: What's the solution for this Mauker?

Comment: no problems when i ran the page through W3C Validator: http://4.1m.yt/pe_KJqQqb.png